# Is there a way to get a RSS feed for an Instagram user/account for free?

Tags: rss, instagram

#### My research so far

I've googled and found several articles which describe outdated services that don't work anymore like

- https://websta.me

And then there are some paid services like these:

- https://rss.app/rss-feed
- https://queryfeed.net/

There are also software packages one could run oneself:

- https://github.com/kenanM/instagram_rss

#### Question

Are there any working free services?

Instagram itself doesn't seem to provide a RSS feed anymore.

I'd like to have some RSS URL that I can add to Feedly which just works.

Comment: Interested in this as well.